# Как начать работать веб-разработчиком?

Tags: работа, веб-программирование

После изучения множества материалов в области веб-разработок, хочется уже начать работать... однако, возникают определённого рода затруднения... на данный момент я могу работать HTML-верстальщиком. Начал изучать jQuery. Но программирование лучше учить на конкретных примерах и задачах, поэтому хотелось стать участником какой-либо команды, в которой можно было бы поучиться.

Но по причине отсутствия портфолио работу найти не получается (никто не хочет связываться с малоопытным работником), сайты по фрилансу тоже не помогают - нет портфолио, а многим заказчикам это важно.

Вот и назревает вопрос: как начать? Как сделать первый шаг? Посоветуйте, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Freelance.ru и подобные для начала. В качестве подготовки без портфолио, плюсы

- свой сайт (ой как постарайтесь сделать его максимально кроссбраузерным). Плюс впилите туда какую-то такую штуку, которая всех удивит =) Я себе скинабельность делал в 1 картинке + 1 css, впечатлило, говорят)
- вместо портфолио - несколько сложнейших задач в верстке, которые вы решили ("Примеры верстки")
- можно попробовать сертификаты какие-то получить
- ...упорство. На постоянку - будьте готовы получать 12-18 в Москве, как курьер. Первое время по крайней мере. По удаленке - будьте готовы писать предложений больше, чем html-кода.

**З.Ы.** и впишите контакты в анкету) мало ли)

Answer (score 9):

Вы описали ситуацию, которая называется catch 22 или, говоря простым языком, замкнутый круг. Вас не берут на работу, потому что у вас нет опыта, а нет опыта потому, что не можете попасть на работу. И мне кажется, что в отличие от других специальностей, IT-специальности имеют конкретные пути выхода.

Но прежде всего...

Рынок труда называется "рынком", потому что им тоже управляет спрос и предложение. Откройте тот же freelance.ru и Вы заметите, что предложение по хтмл-верстальщикам самое большое. Как быть? Тут 2 варианта: либо вы должны быть в этом деле superstar (на что придётся потратить годы), либо нужно искать направления, в которых спрос на сотрудников превышает предложение. (Я говорю о фриланс, локальные аспекты не рассматриваю). Первый опыт работы может быть таким: поставте сами перед собой задачу и реализуйте её. Чем вы занимаетесь помимо работы за компом? Что вам интересно? Может быть вы играете на балалайке? Создайте сайт-портал балалаешников вашей области/города/села. Я например люблю кататься на велосипеде, поэтому первым моим real-world проектом была работа по разработке портала велосипедистов моего города. Создайте сайт чего угодно... детского сада напротив, это может быть ЧТО УГОДНО и совсем не важно, будут ли этот ресурс посещать. Важно, чтобы он был конфеткой в плане исполнения. Это не сколько настоящий опыт, сколько решение реальных задач, столкновение с реальными проблемами и их решение.
А что касается выхода из замкнутого круга, то мой преподаватель называл 2 пути:

1. Работать бесплатно. Т.е. либо как стажёр, практикант. Ведь на данном этапе вам нужен опыт, а не деньги.
2. Работа в OpenSource. Касательно вашего направления работы это может быть поиск энтузиастов в вашем городе, у которых есть интересные мысли отностительно создания какого-либо ресурса, но они не могут реализовать их в одиночку. Вот и присоединитесь к ним, вполне возможно, что не все из них будут такими новичками как вы.

Удачи.

Comment: Кстати, про участие в Open Source проекте: ребята с javatalks.ru объединились в команды и пишут форум и блог. Как раз не хватает людей для "причесывания UI" См. http://www.javatalks.ru/ftopic23892/JavaScript,-CSS,-HTML-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8

Comment: Спасибо большое за вразумительный и толковый совет. Да, на самом деле, деньги для меня не принципиальны на данный момент. Я просто хочу уже наконец "покопаться" (если так можно выразиться) в работе. Но вот не могу прибиться ни к кому в команду... хотя бы тем же стажёром. А оставаться html-верстальщиком не планирую... конечно, буду стараться развиваться, но уже надоело читать книжки, статьи и работать над "учебными" макетами.